# AttributeError: 'FloatProgress' object has no attribute 'style'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science, tqdm, stanza

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

import stanza
stanza.download('en')
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en')
```

above code used for Creating a Pipeline

Stanza provides a plethora of pre-trained NLP models for 66 human languages that we can make use of. Downloading a pre-trained model and creating a pipeline is as easy as:
this code showing this error below shown

```
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/stanza-resources/main/resources_1.5.0.json

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 8
     
----> 8 stanza.download('en')

--> 547     download_resources_json

--> 441 request_file(
 
--> 152     download_file(url, temppath, proxies, raise_for_status)

--> 119 with tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, \
   
--> 245 self.colour = colour

--> 204         self.container.children[-2].style.bar_color = bar_color
```

i have also upgraded jupyter notebook , tqdm and stanza

```
pip install --upgrade stanza
pip install --upgrade tqdm
```

but problem still persist.    this is project regarding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with another library. In the terminal, it works and shows a progress bar, in a notebook-cell it raised the error above.

I worked around the issue by capturing the output of the command that tries to show the progress bar:

```py
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    problematic_function()
```

(The problematic function in my case was SentenceTransformerEmbeddings from langchain)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while loading a model from huggingface:

*model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2')*

Trying this fixed the problem:

**pip install --upgrade ipywidgets**